# Do javascript variables have a storage limit?

Tags: javascript, variables, yui, yui-datatable

Do javascript variables have a storage capacity limit?

I'm designing one YUI datatable where I fetch the data from database and store it in a js object and wherever required I'll extract it and update the YUI datatable. Right now in Dev I've very few records and its storing correctly. In production I may have 1000s of records, this js object is capable to store all these 1000s of records?

If its not capable I'll create on hidden textarea in jsp and store the data there

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript object max size limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926263/javascript-object-max-size-limit)

Comment: What you need to be concerned with is the max number of items an array can store (over 4 billion), and how much data is stored in each field of each record. The limits aren't based on the array as a whole, but rather, each individual piece, For example, integers and strings each have their own limits. You are more likely to hit hardware limits on the client machine **long** before the limits of the data types.

Comment: A couple things to consider - possibly store your data server-only, and retrieve it on demand - that would drastically reduce unnecessary bandwidth. Also, since you mention dev and prod are so different, I always would recommend a production-quality test environment so you don't hit any "gotchas" when going to prod. It's not always cheap, but it's well worth it if you can be more confident in your production deployments.

Comment: @JoeEnos: Thanks for the suggestions Joe. I can't edit the controller on server side coz we are using it at multiple places. If I want to create a seperate controller I ended up with creating 10+ controllers (In future the no may increase based on requirements). Testing the same app in Prod env is a good idea, I'll definately try this if my client permits.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a real prod environment, just something that is as big as prod. One common way is to take a copy of production, identify any personal information (names, addresses, SSN, phone, account number, etc.), then have a script which replaces all of those with random data. If you script it out, you can build a package which refreshes a production-like database at the push of a button.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, objects and arrays have storage limits. They are sufficiently large to be, for most purposes, theoretical. You will be more limited by the VM than the language.

In your specific case (sending thousands of items to a client), you will run into the same problem whether it is JSON, JavaScript, or plain text on the JSP page: client memory. The client is far more likely to run out of usable system memory than you are to run into a language restriction. For thousands of small objects, this shouldn't be an issue.

[Arrays have a limit of 4.2 billion items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript), shown in [the spec at 15.4.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2.2), for example. This is caused by the length being a 32-bit counter. Assuming each element is a single integer, that allows you to store 16GB of numeric data in a single array.

The semantics on objects are more complex, but most functions to work with objects end up using arrays, so you're limited to 4.2 billion keys in most practical scenarios. Again, that's over 16GB of *data*, not counting the overhead to keep references.

The VM, and probably the garbage collector, will start to hang for long periods of time well before you get near the limits of the language. Some implementations will have smaller limits, especially older ones or interpreters. Since the JS spec does not specify *minimum* limits in most cases, those may be implementation-defined and could be much lower ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747068/is-there-a-max-number-of-arguments-javascript-functions-can-accept) on the maximum number of arguments discusses that).

With a good optimizing VM that tries to track the structures you use, at that size, will cause enough overhead that the VM will probably fall back to using maps for your objects (it's theoretically possible to define a struct representing that much data, but not terribly practical). Maps have a small amount of overhead and lookup times get longer as size increases, so you will see performance implications: just not at any reasonable object size.

If you run into another limit, I suspect it will be 65k elements (2^16), [as discussed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9283945/129032). Finding an implementation that supports less than 65k elements seems unlikely, as most browsers were written after 32 bit architectures became the norm.

Comment: Thanks for this knowledge. It looks like in IE9 are some issues with JSON too. There is a comment in Josh Ziegler's article with someone saying that 'In my tests IE9 fail with JSON responses above 40-45MB'

Comment: @RazvanDumitru Your answer has some interesting links. I absolutely believe the JSON (or even JS) parsers will fall down before the language or implementation. Most parsers simply aren't meant for that volume of data at once, although some can handle it. 50MB of JSON is a lot of data to be loading at once.

Answer (score 5):

<del>There isn't such a limit.</del>

It looks that there is a limit at 16GB, but you can read some tests below or in @ssube's answer.

But probably when your object/json is around 50 mb you'll encounter strange behaviour.

For Json here is an interesting article : http://josh.zeigler.us/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/

For Js Object you have more knowledge here: [javascript object max size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926263/javascript-object-max-size-limit) (saying that there isn't such a limit but encounter strange behaviour at ~40 mb)

Comment: Seems there is some problwm with IE when dealing with heavy data. Default browser in my project is IE8. Hope that records size wont cross 50gb. :P

Answer (score 1):

The limit depends on the available memory of the browser. So every PC, Mac, Mobile setup will give you a different limit.
I don't know how much memory one of your records needs, but I would guess that 1000 records should work on the most machines.

**But**: You should avoid storing massive data amounts in simple variables, depending on the records memory it slows down the whole website behavior. Your users with average computers may see ugly scrolling effects, delayed hover effects and so on..

I would recommend you to use local storage. I'm sorry to don't know the YUI library, but I am pretty sure that you can point to the storage for your datatable source.

Comment: Mine is a internal application (end users are company employees only). Earlier they used to store the data in a local variable and display all the data at a time, but in my re-design I'm storing all the data and displaying part of the data and based on requierments I'm extracting and using it. So it reduced the page loading time drastically.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on JavaScript objects [max js object limit](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-JavaScript-object-in-browser-memory). What i would suggest using is session objects because that's what it sounds like your trying to do anyway.