# What is the maximum size an object can have on the browser? (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory, browser

I do some data manipulation on the browser and I use an object (of arrays) as a local DB where I store and query things for the duration of the page session.

My question is, how big is this object of arrays allowed to get on the browser? The data I'm storing are images as Base64 strings. I'm assuming I cannot be adding things to it indefinitely there should be some maximum size allowed ?

Comment: Array `length` counter is unsigned 32-bit integer, making the maximum no. of items in an array be no more than 2<sup>32</sup>-1.  As for the actual size of the object, there's no limit set by the language itself, however the resources available on the machine becomes the limit. There are a few discussions on such limitations - [variable size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194088/do-javascript-variables-have-a-storage-limit), [array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript).