# Too many properties in a js object

Tags: javascript

Can there be to many properties in a js object?

I want to build a site similar to [workaway.info](http://www.workaway.info), and am thinking about how to design the search component. Under advanced search options they have about 30 checkboxes for various types of work. Multiple work types can be included in each job listing.

Would it be typical to have a `boolean` property for each checkbox option in the object or one `array` containing the `boolean` input for all of the options?

Any reason to pick one over the other?

```
    ...
//Method 1:
function Job(theCompany, thePosition){
  this.company = theCompany;
  this.position = thePosition;
  this.isMedical = true;
  this.isAdministrative = true;
  this.isLaw = false;
  ...
  }

//Method 2:
function Job(theCompany, thePosition){
  this.company = theCompany;
  this.position = thePosition;
  this.typeOptions = [true, true, false...];
  ...
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Generally, [the property limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9283945/2325803) is 65535. Since you won't hit that limit, your question is purely style.

I think my preferred way of doing this would be to have an array of string flags. For example:

```
function Job(theCompany, thePosition) {
    this.company = theCompany;
    this.position = thePosition;
    this.typeOptions = ['medical', 'administrative'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no perfect answer here, and it will change drastically based on programming style.

One thing I'd advise against is your second option, in a literal sense;

```
options = [ true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, false, false, false, /*...*/];
```

It's impossible to have any understanding of what each of those does, while keeping in the context of the code.

Boolean properties on a single object are fine, but become unwieldy when you're talking about dozens, let alone tens of thousands of properties, on a single object, at the same nesting level.

In more modern browsers (or older browsers with ES5 polyfills), I feel this is a prime candidate for Set;

```
var options = new Set();

form.onchange = function (e) {
  var el = e.target;
  if (isCheckbox(el)) {
    if (el.checked) {
      options.add( el.value );
    } else {
      options.delete( el.value );
    }
  }
};
```

The reason I might write it this way is so that the code for adding the keys doesn't really need to know anything about the keys.

In larger applications, having a generic approach, where data is fed into a framework (React/Angular/Ember/etc/hand-made) which automatically builds your form, listens for events, and pulls values from the dynamically-built page in a fashion like this, makes it a little harder to reason about, but also makes it much easier to add, remove or modify options, down the road, as only the code that displays the option, and the code which use the value need to care.

```
const formOptions = [
  { label: "Medical", value: "medical" },
  { label: "Legal", value: "legal" }
];

const form = buildForm(formOptions);
/* ...previous code... */
form.onsubmit = function () {
  Array.from(options). /* map, filter, forEach, reduce, etc */( ... );
};
```

The rest of the code, in between, is just wiring.

Again, not perfect; not the only answer, but one take, and why.

Answer (score 0):

Pick method 1: for easy maintain code , anyone read your code will know exactly what value mean

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `method 1` as it gives developer to access the property name in some meaningful way by its name which is meaningful and not by indexing of array.
This method help developer  for better debugging in future.If you use array,developer is completely relay on your comments and business logic to find out the exact  purpose of each element in the array which make debugging very difficult.`Method 1` helps for very good debugging and also follow standard that every variable should have some meaningful name.