# How hashtable makes sure object keys are hashed into a unique index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hashtable, unique

After looking at a simple [hash table implementation](https://gist.github.com/alexhawkins/f6329420f40e5cafa0a4) in JavaScript, the key index is computed as:

```
function index(str, max) {
  var hash = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var letter = str[i];
    hash = (hash << 5) + letter.charCodeAt(0);
    hash = (hash & hash) % max;
  }
  return hash;
}
```

So I'm wondering in the case of v8, how it uses a function similar to that but makes sure the index is unique on the object. So if you do this:

```
{ a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }
```

Then it becomes something like:

```
var i = index('a', 100000)
// 97
var j = index('b', 100000)
// 98
```

But if you have 100's or 1000's or more keys on an object, it seems like there might be collisions.

Wondering how a hashtable guarantees they are unique, using v8 as a practical example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282869/are-there-limits-to-the-number-of-properties-in-a-javascript-object

Comment: No, any hashtable implementation needs some way to handle collisions. If hashes were guaranteed to be unique, they would not have any size benefit.

Comment: You cannot predict the size of a string set, hence there will be collisions at some point. However, collisions can be handled with collections as simple as queues.

Comment: Looking to know how to do that, that sounds like a good solution.

Comment: @Bergi: Actually there is such a thing as a [perfect hash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), which has no collisions and no wasted space, but it's not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V8 developer here. Hashes of strings are not unique (that's kind of the point of using a hash function); V8 uses quadratic probing to deal with collisions (see [source](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/objects/hash-table.h?type=cs&q=NextProbe%20package:%5Echromium$&l=124)). You can read more about various strategies at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution.

Also, `hash = (hash & hash) % max;` is pretty silly ;-)